# SBS 2011 unable to browse \\domain\share

Tags: windows, windows-sbs-2011

We have a customer that has a small SBS 2011 server.

It has come to light after a new PC install that we are unable to browse any UNC path that includes the domain name.

for example.

If I was to ping the domain name, I would get a response fine. If I was to do a nslookup of the domain name it would resolve fine. But if I was to navigate to a UNC share \DOMAINNAME\SHARE either from the server or from another PC I would recieve an error message stating:

The Specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

This is obviously affecting machines from pulling group policies from the Sysvol as they request \domainname\sysvol on start-up.

If I was to browse \IPADDRESS\SHARE or \MACHINENAME.DOMAINNAME\SHARE this would work fine?

When researching this other people suggest that this could be a DNS issue, but I can't see why this would be if I can resolve names fine.

It is worth noting that this is for any share on the server and I've also tried to remove the share and recreate it.

This has been working fine for a couple of years since install.

Any suggestions?